# Browser versioning problem for selenium automation testing with google chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

When I want to send a key on google.com using selenium automation testing with google chrome then I ahve faced a error like the picture and code is

```
public ActionResult selenium()
    {
        IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Selenium");
        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to change ChromeDriver version bcs you have 85v and mybe your browser is with another version you need to check if the browser is a 85 version if it not desanstaled the browser and install version 85